# How do I trigger a DIH import using DIH Commands

Tags: solr, dih

Solr is set up correctly and I can import data using the DIH Data Import Handler manually - i.e. using the user interface.

I am having trouble triggering the import via HTTP Request - Is there a setting for turning this on or what else could I be missing. I am simply hitting the url:

```
https://url.net/solr/#/corename/dataimport//dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true
```

I don't know wny dataimport is in the url twice but i've tried it with it in only once and still doesn't work.

All this does is load up the data import UI in solr admin, and I can see the last successful import time - the one I did manually via the UI - I've tried to hit it using Chrome browser, postman and via a powershell script.

I think I'm missing something simple but not sure what...?

Comment: can you try "http://host:port/solr/dih/dataimport?command=full-import"

Comment: did you tried through solr admin page

Comment: yes it works via the admin page

Comment: 404 if I use the url you have suggested @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: this is the standard "http://<host>:<port>/solr/dataimport?command=full-import"

Comment: can you check in the developer tool whats url it it hitting?

Comment: using that standard how does it know which core to import data for?

Comment: new to solr - where's the developer tool?

Comment: go to the solr admin page in browser...open the browsers developer tool and check whats the url is built by solr

Comment: Ahah - so the url used when you hit the execute button in the UI is like: `https://URL.net/solr/corename/dataimport?_=1564047317989&indent=on&wt=json` I have tried to hit that and it appears to have worked - but need to give it a bit of time so I can check "started time"... the response from the request looks positive though. Thanks. I have tried the same format with the query string set to `command=full-import&commit=true` and that also works so basically you don't need the `/#/` bit or the 2nd `dataimport`

Comment: Can I mark "https://URL.net/solr/corename/dataimport?_=1564047317989&indent=on&wt=json" this as an answer ?

Comment: Sure. Add an answer and I’ll upvote. Thanks

Comment: `#` denotes a local anchor and anything after it is never sent to the server itself. It's handled by the browser (and through javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url for the `dataimport` for in `solr` is like :

```
https://URL.net/solr/corename/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true&indent=on&wt=json
```